# How to render an array within a JSON object in react-native

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am developing an app with react-native , using RESTfull api with laravel backend , I have an object that has arrays in it . I am using it to create user's profile page . but I don't know how to render those arrays.
here is my api response:

```js
{
  meta: {
    code: 200,
    message: 'Success',
    errors: []
  },
  data: {
    users: [
      {
        personal_information: {
          full_name: 'hesam sameni',
          avatar: 'https://aaa/file/image/hesamsameni.jpeg',
          rate: '0.0',
          phone: [],
          location: {
            name: 'something',
            lat: 00,
            long: 00,
            address: 'something',
            distance: 00
          },
          about: {
            quote: 'something',
            bio: 'something'
          },
          topics: {
            a: 'a',
            b: 'b',
            c: 'c',
            d: 'd'
          },
          stats: {
            a: 10,
            b: 0,
            c: 0,
            d: 0,
            e: 0
          },
          experiences: [
            {
              title: 'something',
              organization: 'something',
              start: 'something',
              end: 'something'
            }
          ],
          educations: [
            {
              title: 'something1',
              university: 'something1',
              major: 'something1',
              start: 'something1',
              end: 'something1'
            },
            {
              title: 'something2',
              university: 'something2',
              major: 'something2',
              start: 'something2',
              end: 'something2'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

For example how can I show educations in user's profile?

here is the render method ( I already got data from api and stored in state `{this.state.dataSource}`

render method:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>Name: {item.personal_information.full_name}</Text>
            <Text>Rate: {item.personal_information.Rate}</Text>
            <Text>Educations:</Text>
            // Here I need to display all of user's educations
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I am not sure if I had to use flatlist since it is only data for 1 specific user , but I didn't know how to render data in other way than flatlist .

Comment: did you use `this.setState` to update data in state?

Comment: Yes I can render items which are not in array , e.g I can render full_name and rate but I want to render both items in education array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it will help you achive  what you want.
  if not tell me..

```
     <FlatList
  data={this.state.itemArray}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({item}) =>{
    console.warn(item.data.users[0].personal_information.educations)
  return(<FlatList
data={item.data.users[0].personal_information.educations}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => "D"+index.toString()}
renderItem={({item}) =>{
console.warn(item)
}
}/>)
  }
}/>
```

if u want to get something from personal_information
try this example : `console.warn(item.data.users[0].personal_information.full_name)`

Comment: I can get the full_name and other things that are not array , but I want to render both items in educations

Comment: You suggest to use flatlist inside the flatlist? I'll give it a try

Comment: u can user even https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/sectionlist  section list for this also

Answer (score 0):

So `.map` itself only offers one value you care about... That said, there are a few ways of tackling this:

```
// instantiation
this.state.dataSource

//Using `.map` directlly
this.state.dataSource.map((obj, index)=> {
    console.log(obj);
    return(
        <View />
    )
});

// what's built into Map for you
this.state.dataSource.forEach( (val, key) => console.log(key, val) ); 

// what Array can do for you
Array.from( this.state.dataSource ).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));

// less awesome iteration
let entries = this.state.dataSource.entries( );
for (let entry of entries) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

Note, I'm using a lot of new stuff in that second example... `...Array`.from takes any iterable (any time you'd use `[].slice.call( )`, plus Sets and Maps) and turns it into an array... ...Maps, when coerced into an array, turn into an array of arrays, where `el[0] === key && el[1] === value`; (basically, in the same format that I prefilled my example Map with, above).

I'm using destructuring of the array in the argument position of the lambda, to assign those array spots to values, before returning an object for each el.

If you're using Babel, in production, you're going to need to use Babel's browser polyfill (which includes "core-js" and Facebook's "regenerator").
I'm quite certain it contains `Array.from`.

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
     console.log(this.state.data.users[0].personal_information.educations,'cdscdscdcds')
    return(
        <div>

            {this.state.data.users.map((value)=>{
                console.log(value,'cd')
            })}
        </div>
```